# How to create duplicate values in database using id in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here i already have a row which contains the values, i have a id as a primary key
now what i want to do is using that id i want to duplicate the same row values and create another row.except i want to update 2 column values. how can i do this?

for ex:
in one row i already have the values say

```
product_id,product_price,product_nos,product_remaining,product_name
```

now i want to duplicate the above row with changing only one column value
,say `product_remaining` set value to 10.

How can i do this in php or with query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query if you not use auto_incrementing ids, 10 is the new value for product_remaining.

```
 INSERT INTO table (product_price,product_nos,product_remaining,product_name)
    SELECT product_price,product_nos,10,product_name FROM table
      WHERE product_id = 1
```

or this one where you set your id, where 999 is the new id:

```
 INSERT INTO table (product_id,product_price,product_nos,product_remaining,product_name)
    SELECT 999,product_price,product_nos,10,product_name FROM table
      WHERE product_id = 1
```